# docpad as blogging engine, pagination and problems related to many posts?

Tags: pagination, blogs, docpad

I spent the last day setting up docpad as a blogging engine, starting from https://github.com/balupton/website 
After getting everything working and looking the way I like it I came to one last issue -

In the page showing all blog posts I output document.contentRenderedWithoutLayouts for each document in @documents.

I have to be ready to handle a reasonably big blog

This means I need to do pagination.

What seems like the best way to do that? 
I was thinking having posts in subfolders inside of blog, but then I have to iterate folders
 assume each folder is a page paginate to next page 
need to also sort so that the folder with the newest posts is the first, the folder with the next latest is rendered as page 2

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your best bet is the [Paged Plugin](http://docpad.org/p/paged), it will automatically split a specified document into multiple documents, and inject them into the database. Does that work for you?

Comment: I guess I will try that, looks counter intuitive, I guess I would think something like

Comment: I guess I will try that, looks counter intuitive, I guess I would normally think something like - @documents is array, get length divide by 10 tells number of pages, take index out render that part so multiple pages that way - so @documents[0 to 10] is first page and so forth. Seem reasonable?